# Empty memoir header

Tags: header-footer

In my book I use the memoir class and the code for even and odd page header is as follows:

```
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{{\large{\color{evenPageColor}{\textbf{\thepage}}}}$\ \ \ \ $ \color{evenTextColor}{\large\textsection$\,$\lastrightmark}}{}{}

\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{}{\large \color{oddTextColor}{\leftmark} $\ \ \ \ $ {\large{\textbf {\color{oddPageColor}{\thepage}}}}}
```

The result of these settings is that in the header of the odd pages it prints, for example,

CHAPTER 35, QUANTUM MECHANICS (namely, chapter number and name)  1388 (page number), right alligned

while, in the header of the even pages, it prints, for example,

1387 (namely, page number) 35.2 BLACKBODY RADIATION (namely section name), left aligned

The problem is that in this chapter the first \section command is found after a large body of introductory text and since there is no section in the second page (the first page of each chapter is just a figure), the header of this (and only this) even page displays only the page number and nothing more. Since i do not like this, i want to add in this specific page header an informal text (e.g. INTRODUCTORY NOTES) in the place of the (null) section title. It seems that i have to modify the \lastrightmark variable (if I understood  correctly). How can i do this?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. BTW I'm confused as to why on odd page you get a page number like 1388, while on even pages a page number like 1397.

Comment: Can't try it out because you haven't given a document, but maybe this works: `\markright{INTRODUCTORY NOTES}` after the `\chapter{...}` command.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot !